# Selector.select() does not block

Tags: java, selector

Sorry, I searched around for 2 days before I had to post this question. There are similar questions, but none of them helped me.

I am trying to create a simple chat application where the client uses (non-NIO) Socket to connect to the server that listens with a NIO ServerSocketChannel. The server uses a Selector. Until the first client connects, the Selector.select() method is blocked, as expected. But after the first client connects, Selector.select() does not block and returns immediately. This causes my while loop to run continuously.

Sorry, I've pasted the entire code so that you can copy-paste it and run it. I've just started with Java, so any help/pointers will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S.: Right now, the client sends serialized object (Message object) over the socket connection and the Server reads it. Since the connection is non-blocking, the serialized object is pre-fixed with the object size (in bytes) before it is sent to the server. This allows the server to read the next "x" bytes and un-serialize into a Message object. The server code is a work in progress.

CLIENT CODE----------

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ChatClient {

    void go(){
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("UserA");
        try{
            u.setInet(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        }catch (UnknownHostException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            return;
        }
        Message m = new Message();
        m.setType(3);
        m.setText("This is the 1st message.");
        m.setFromUser(u);
        try{
            Socket sock = new Socket (InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 5000);
            DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream()); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteTemp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream (byteTemp);
            objOut.writeObject(m);
            objOut.flush();
            objOut.close();

            byte[] byteMessage = byteTemp.toByteArray();
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            bb.putInt(byteMessage.length);
            byte[] size = new byte[4];
            size = bb.array();
            System.out.println("Object size = "+byteMessage.length); //370

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byteOut.write(size);
            byteOut.write(byteMessage);

            byte[] finalMessage = byteOut.toByteArray();
            dataOut.write(finalMessage,0,finalMessage.length);
            dataOut.flush();
            System.out.println("Flushed out");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        new CopyOfChatClient().go();
    }
}
```

SERVER CODE ---------------

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
    import java.nio.channels.Selector;
    import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
    import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

    public class CopyOfChatServer {
        Object a, b;//Dummy objects for synchronization
        SocketChannel clientSock=null;
        Selector selector;
        SelectionKey key;

        void go(){
            try{
                a=new Object();//Dummy objects for synchronization
                b=new Object();//Dummy objects for synchronization
                ServerSocketChannel serverSock = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                serverSock.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
                //Note: ServerSocketChannel is blocking, but each new connection returned by accept() will be made non-blocking (see below)
                selector = Selector.open();
                new Thread(new SelectorThread()).start(); //Start the SelectorThread
                int i=0;
                while (true){               
                    clientSock = serverSock.accept();
                    if (clientSock!=null){                  
                        clientSock.configureBlocking(false); //The default client socket returned by accept() is blocking. Set it to non-blocking.                          
                        synchronized (b){
                            selector.wakeup();
                            synchronized (a){
                                key = clientSock.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);  //register new client Socket with selector  
                                key.attach(clientSock);
                            }//sync(a)
                        }//sync(b)              
                        i++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Here");
                }//while(true)

            }catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        class SelectorThread implements Runnable{
            Set <SelectionKey> selectedKeys;
            int readyChannels;
            public void run(){
                while (true){               
                        try {
                            synchronized(a){
                                System.out.println("1. Selector trying to select");
                                readyChannels = selector.select();//Note: select() is blocking ?? Does not block. Behaves like non-blocking
                                System.out.println("2. Selector has selected");
                            }//sync a

                            synchronized (b){
                                //just wait till registration is done in main thread
                            }

                            if (readyChannels == 0) continue; //Even if select() is blocking, this check is to handle suprious wake-ups
                            System.out.println("readyChannels>0");
                            selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
                            while (keyIterator.hasNext()){
                                SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                    keyIterator.remove();//added after the first answer to my question
                                if (key.isReadable()){
                                    System.out.println("3. Got incoming data");
                                    SocketChannel tempSock = (SocketChannel)key.attachment();
                                    ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocate(8000);
                                    int bytesRead=tempSock.read(bb);
                                    System.out.println("4. Bytes read = "+bytesRead);
                                    if (bytesRead>4){
                                        bb.flip();
                                        bb.rewind();

                                        int size = bb.getInt();
                                        System.out.println("5. Size of object = "+size);
                                        byte[] objIn = new byte[size];
                                        for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
                                            objIn[i]=bb.get();
                                        }
                                        bb.compact();

                                        ByteArrayInputStream bIn= new ByteArrayInputStream(objIn);
                                        ObjectInputStream objStream= new ObjectInputStream(bIn);
                                        Message temp1 = (Message) objStream.readObject();
                                        System.out.println("6. Read object back");
                                        System.out.println(temp1.getFromUser().getName());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            selectedKeys.clear();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 

                }
            }
        }

        public static void main (String args[]){
            new CopyOfChatServer().go();
        }
    }
```

MESSAGE Class ----

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable{
    private int type; 
    private User fromUser;
    private User toUser;
    private String text;

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public User getFromUser() {
        return fromUser;
    }
    public void setFromUser(User fromUser) {
        this.fromUser = fromUser;
    }
    public User getToUser() {
        return toUser;
    }
    public void setToUser(User toUser) {
        this.toUser = toUser;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

USER CLASS --------

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class User implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private InetAddress inet;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public InetAddress getInet() {
        return inet;
    }
    public void setInet(InetAddress inet) {
        this.inet = inet;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put

```
keyIterator.remove()
```

after

```
keyIterator.next()
```

The selector doesn't remove anything from selectedKeys() itself.

NB You don't need to attach the channel to the key as an attachment. You can get it from key.channel().

Comment: I don't see anything else, but this is pretty strange code. You've picked one of the hardest cases for NIO in Serialization, and you haven't done it right. You're assuming the entire object arrives in one read, for example, and if it doesn't, or the length word doesn't arrive in a single read, you're going to get completely out of sync. Also you would be better off using a single thread with the server socket channel in non-blocking mode: then you could get rid of all the synchronization. But I question whether you should be using NIO at all. It would be much easier in java.net.

Comment: True. As I've mentioned, my server code is not complete. I still need to tune it. I thought I will proceed after I figure out what is causing select() to return instantly. Your question on whether to use NIO is completely valid. This is more for learning than for a practical application.

Comment: You've also overlooked that ObjectOutputStream writes a stream header which is read by ObjectInputStream. So if you're constructing a new ObjectInputStream per read, you need to construct a new ObjectOutputStream per write: in other words yet another way you can get out of sync.